# Inline purified PostScript (MPS)

Tags: graphics, pdf, metapost, postscript

I just learned [how to inline PDF code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174252/include-pdf-via-pdfliteral) using the `\pdfliteral` command and that purified Encapsulated PostScript generated by METAPOST or `purifyeps` can be converted to PDF code by pdfLaTeX.

However, I have been unable to find the actual conversion code I need for embedding the transformed EPS via `\pdfliteral`.

I would like to have something like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \begin{purifiedeps}
        %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
        %%BoundingBox: 0 0 33 31 
        %%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 32.0781 30.9844 
        %%Creator: MetaPost 1.803
        %%CreationDate: 2014.04.30:1514
        %%Pages: 1
        %%BeginProlog
        %%EndProlog
        %%Page: 1 1
         0 0 0 setrgbcolor
        newpath 28.9375 30.1875 moveto
        16.0312 7.76563 lineto
        3.14063 30.1875 lineto
        2.82813 30.6406 2.23438 30.9844 1.64063 30.9844 curveto
        0.84375 30.9844 0 30.3906 0 29.5312 curveto
        0 1.5 lineto
        0 0.64063 0.73438 0 1.64063 0 curveto
        2.57813 0 3.28125 0.64063 3.28125 1.5 curveto
        3.28125 23.3594 lineto
        7.0625 16.8281 10.7969 10.3125 14.5469 3.78125 curveto
        14.7969 3.28125 15.3906 2.98438 16.0312 2.98438 curveto
        16.7344 2.98438 17.125 3.39063 17.5312 3.78125 curveto
        21.2656 10.3125 25 16.8281 28.7812 23.3594 curveto
        28.7812 1.5 lineto
        28.7812 0.64063 29.4844 0 30.4375 0 curveto
        31.3281 0 32.0781 0.64063 32.0781 1.5 curveto
        32.0781 29.4844 lineto
        32.0781 30.3281 31.2344 30.9844 30.4375 30.9844 curveto
        29.8281 30.9844 29.2344 30.7344 28.9375 30.1875 curveto
         closepath fill
        showpage
        %%EOF
    \end{purifiedeps}
\end{document}
```

where the `purifiedeps` environment still has to be defined.

The EPS code yields the METAPOST-`M`:

[image]

NOTE: I know that it's possible to `\includegraphics{somepurifiedeps.mps}` but I am searching for an inline solution not requiring an external file.

**EDIT:** I think I gathered the relavant pieces from the ConTeXt package `supp-pdf`:

```
\def\convertMPtoPDF % #1#2#3%
  {\bgroup
   \defineMPtoPDFfallbacks
   \ifx\pdfdecimaldigits\undefined\else \pdfdecimaldigits=5 \fi % new
   \setbox\scratchbox\vbox\bgroup
     \xdef\MPheight{0pt}%
     \xdef\MPwidth {0pt}%
     \forgetall
     \offinterlineskip
     \startMPresources
     \doprocessMPtoPDFfile} %

\def\doprocessMPtoPDFfile#1#2#3% file xscale yscale
  {\setMPspecials
   \setMPextensions
   \the\everyMPtoPDFconversion
   \catcode`\^^M=\@@endofline
   \startMPscanning
   \let\do\empty
   \xdef\MPxscale{#2}%
   \xdef\MPyscale{#3}%
   \xdef\MPxoffset{0}%
   \xdef\MPyoffset{0}%
   \xdef\MPyshift{0pt}%
   \donefalse
   \let\handleMPsequence\dohandleMPsequence
   \message{[MP to PDF]}% was: [MP to PDF #1] but there is a (#1) anyway
   \input#1\relax}
```

`\convertMPtoPDF{test.mps}{0.5}{0.5}` will include the purified EPS file `test.mps` scaled by a factor of 0.5. To build an inline version of this command, I would need to replace `\input#1` in `\doprocessMPtoPDFfile` with a macro containing the definition of the EPS code.

Unfortunatly, I don't know how to define such a macro since I need to preserve EPS comments (`%`) as well as line breaks. Hence, the macro definition needs to contain the verbatim (unprocessed) EPS code. How could I do that?

Comment: Look in pdftex.def (the log of the latex run shows you where that is) that inputs some of Hans' code from context do to this `\InputIfFileExists{supp-pdf.mkii}{}{%
      \InputIfFileExists{supp-pdf}{}{}%
    }%`

Comment: Is environment `filecontents` an option?

Answer (score 9):

You need `supp-pdf.mkii`, see its comments for details.

The hard part is to get the MPS file into a macro (or token register).
Macro `\savemps` saves the MPS code as macro. Care need to be taken for
the percent characters and the line ends should be preserved.

Macro `\includemps` is then quite easy, it calls `\convertMPtoPDF` with
a redefined `\input` that rereads the image stored in a macro as file via
e-TeX's `\scantokens`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{supp-pdf.mkii}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\savemps}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@sanitize % verbatim catcodes
  \catcode`\ =10 % except space
  \catcode`\^^A=14 % new comment char
  % keep lines:
  \@makeother\^^J% Line feed as character
  \endlinechar=`\^^J % end lines with line feed
  \savemps@{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\savemps@}[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \def#1{#2}%
  % catch odd new line
  \futurelet\@let@token\savemps@gobbleLF
}
\newcommand*{\savemps@gobbleLF}{%
  \ifx\@let@token\includemps@J
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
}
\begingroup
  \lccode`\9=`\^^J %
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \let\includemps@J=9%
}
\newcommand*{\includemps}[3]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\input##1\relax{\scantokens\expandafter{##1}}%
    \convertMPtoPDF{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\savemps\mympsimage{
  %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
  %%BoundingBox: 0 0 33 31 
  %%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 32.0781 30.9844 
  %%Creator: MetaPost 1.803
  %%CreationDate: 2014.04.30:1514
  %%Pages: 1
  %%BeginProlog
  %%EndProlog
  %%Page: 1 1
   0 0 0 setrgbcolor
  newpath 28.9375 30.1875 moveto
  16.0312 7.76563 lineto
  3.14063 30.1875 lineto
  2.82813 30.6406 2.23438 30.9844 1.64063 30.9844 curveto
  0.84375 30.9844 0 30.3906 0 29.5312 curveto
  0 1.5 lineto
  0 0.64063 0.73438 0 1.64063 0 curveto
  2.57813 0 3.28125 0.64063 3.28125 1.5 curveto
  3.28125 23.3594 lineto
  7.0625 16.8281 10.7969 10.3125 14.5469 3.78125 curveto
  14.7969 3.28125 15.3906 2.98438 16.0312 2.98438 curveto
  16.7344 2.98438 17.125 3.39063 17.5312 3.78125 curveto
  21.2656 10.3125 25 16.8281 28.7812 23.3594 curveto
  28.7812 1.5 lineto
  28.7812 0.64063 29.4844 0 30.4375 0 curveto
  31.3281 0 32.0781 0.64063 32.0781 1.5 curveto
  32.0781 29.4844 lineto
  32.0781 30.3281 31.2344 30.9844 30.4375 30.9844 curveto
  29.8281 30.9844 29.2344 30.7344 28.9375 30.1875 curveto
   closepath fill
  showpage
  %%EOF
}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\fbox{%
  \includemps{\mympsimage}{1}{1}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Fantastic! I already started to fiddle around with the catcodes but I could not get it working!

Comment: ... and redefining `\input` locally is even more elegant then copying code from `supp-pdf.mkii`.