Rule based tikz picture
i have the following graphic, which was created using matplotlib in Python. However I don't like the way I looks (looks so shrinkers) and I was wondering if it is possible to recreate something in Latex. The base should be a box with Days on the y-axis and Worker on the x-axis. Then the box is divided in $x\times y$ equal size squares, where $x$ is the number for the x-axis and $y$ for the y-axis. Each box should be outlined by a fine line. Now comes the rule into play. I predefined two values for $x$ and $y$ and I have a sequence of numbers as an input. This list contains only the values of 0,1 2 and 3. Now based on the value of $y$ the list should be defined in $y$ equal sized 'sublists'. Now we go from left to right. And start at the top from at y-axis point of view. Whenever the value in the sublist is a zero, the little box remains white, if it is 1 is it filled orange, for 2 with violet and for 3 the field is diagonally split with orange and violet (as seen in the picture). If this is done for box 1, the next number in the sublist is looked at. This as done as long as the sublist has entries. Then the Next sublist is used for the second from top row, as long as till every field is filled. How would I achieve this?

I came up with this solution so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\cellsize}
\let\END=\eof

\newcommand{\colormatrix}[1]% #1 = binary matrix
{\parbox{\CMcolumns\cellsize}{%
  \baselineskip=\cellsize
  \lineskip=0pt
  \def\one{1}%
  \def\two{2}%
  \def\three{3}%
  \def\zero{0}%
  \bgroup
    \countdef\col=1
    \col=0
    \CMParse#1\END
  \egroup
}}

\def\CMParse#1{\ifx#1\END\else
  \if#1\one\relax{\color{\onecolor}\rule{\cellsize}{\cellsize}}\fi
  \if#1\two\relax{\color{\twocolor}\rule{\cellsize}{\cellsize}}\fi
  \if#1\three\relax{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\cellsize,y=\cellsize]
      \fill[orange] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
      \fill[violet] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }\fi
  \if#1\zero\relax{\color{\zerocolor}\rule{\cellsize}{\cellsize}}\fi
  \advance\col by 1
  \ifnum\col<\CMcolumns\relax\else
    \hfil
    \col=0
  \fi
\expandafter\CMParse\fi}% expand \fi first

\newcommand{\setcolormatrix}[6]% #1=width, #2=height, #3=number columns, #4=one color, #5=two color, #6=zero color
{\global\cellsize=\dimexpr #1/#3\relax
 \global\def\CMcolumns{#3}%
 \global\def\onecolor{#4}%
 \global\def\twocolor{#5}%
 \global\def\zerocolor{#6}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\setcolormatrix{\textwidth}{\textwidth}{11}{violet}{orange}{white}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (matrix) at (0,0) {
    \colormatrix{%
      101101013101232312101101013101232312
      100101010101232323101101013101232312
      010101110101231223101101013101232312
      111100101001221223101101013101232312
      011000110011231223101101013101232312
      111010101110121223101101013101232312
      101010101110121223101101013101232312
    }
  };
  \draw (matrix.south west) rectangle (matrix.north east);
  \node[below] at (matrix.south) {Worker};
  \node[left, rotate=90] at (matrix.west) {Days};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

However it does not adhere to the textwidth and the axises are nor well labelled.
EDIT:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pxpic,tikz}

% from pxpic-documentation, minor change in using lightgrey
\newcommand\gridpxpic[3][]
  {{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{#2}%
    \colorbox{lightgray}{\pxpic[gap-hack=0pt,#1]{#3}}% Removed negative fboxsep to fix gaps
  }}

% Rest of the package definitions remain the same...
\pxpicnewmode{lukdooxb1}
  {%
    \ifcase#1
      {\color{white}\px}\or
      {\color{orange}\px}\or
      {\color{violet}\px}\or
      \diagpxnoborder{orange}{violet}%
    \else
      \GenericError{}{Unknown input symbol #1}{}{}%
    \fi
  }

\newcommand\diagpxnoborder[2]
  {%
    \begin{pgfpicture}
      % Draw the first triangle
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \color{#1}%
      \pgfusepath{fill}%
      % Draw the second triangle (corrected overlap)
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \color{#2}%
      \pgfusepath{fill}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
  }

% Keep the auxiliary counting commands unchanged...
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__lukdooxb_columns_int
\int_new:N \l__lukdooxb_rows_int
\newcount \graphRows
\newcount \graphColumns
\NewDocumentCommand\getCounts{m}
  {
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \lukdooxb_get_counts:n
    \graphRows = \int_use:N \l__lukdooxb_rows_int \exp_stop_f:
    \graphColumns = \int_use:N \l__lukdooxb_columns_int \exp_stop_f:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \lukdooxb_get_counts:n #1
  {
    \__lukdooxb_get_counts_columns:w #1 ~ \q_nil
    \int_set:Nn \l__lukdooxb_rows_int
      { \__lukdooxb_count_rows:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_get_counts_columns:w #1 ~ #2\q_nil
  { \int_set:Nn \l__lukdooxb_columns_int { \tl_count:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_count_rows:n #1
  {
    0
    \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w #1 ~ \q_nil
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w #1 ~ #2
  {
    +1
    \quark_if_nil:nF {#2} \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Modified frontend macro with adjusted offsets
\newcommand\graph[2][\linewidth]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \getCounts{#2}%
      % set the pixel size such that the size target will be met
      \sbox{0}{\fontsize{8}{8} Day}%
      \pxpicsetup
        {size=(#1-8mm-\ht0-\dp0)/\graphColumns,mode=lukdooxb1,lines=space}% Increased from 4mm to 8mm
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
           ytik/.style={tik, anchor=south east, xshift=-3pt}% Increased offset
          ,xtik/.style={tik, anchor=north, xshift=-.5ex, yshift=-3pt}% Increased offset
          ,tik/.style={inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize}
        ]
        % main plot
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (px) {\gridpxpic{.2pt}{#2}};
        % days ticks with increased offset
        \node[font=\footnotesize, ytik] at ([yshift=-1\pxpicHT]px.north west) {1};
        \ifnum\graphRows>6
          \ifnum\graphRows>13
            \foreach\x in{7, 14, ..., \graphRows}
              \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-\x\pxpicHT]px.north west) {\x};
          \else
            \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-7\pxpicHT]px.north west) {7};
          \fi
        \fi
        \node[font=\footnotesize, rotate=90] at ([xshift=-7mm]px.west) {Day};% Increased offset from 4mm to 6mm
        % worker ticks
        \node[font=\footnotesize, xtik] at ([xshift=1\pxpicWD]px.south west) {1};
        \ifnum\graphColumns>24
          \ifnum\graphColumns>49
            \foreach\x in{25, 50, ..., \graphColumns}
              \node[xtik] at ([xshift=\x\pxpicWD]px.south west) {\x};
          \else
            \node[xtik] at ([xshift=25\pxpicWD]px.south west) {25};
          \fi
        \fi
        \node[font=\footnotesize] at ([yshift=-7mm]px.south) (tmp) {\fontsize{8}{8} Worker};% Increased offset from 4mm to 6mm
        % Modify the legend to include the diagonal split box
% legend with tighter spacing and improved alignment
\node[anchor=north, font=\footnotesize, fill=white, draw=black, inner sep=1.5mm, rounded corners] at ([yshift=-1mm]tmp.south)
  {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{\hspace{3mm}}c@{\hspace{1mm}}l@{}}
      \raisebox{0.3ex}{\gridpxpic{.1pt}{1}} & Model1 &
      \raisebox{0.3ex}{\gridpxpic{.1pt}{2}} & Model2 &
      % Use diagpxnoborder for the diagonal box in legend
      \raisebox{0.3ex}{\gridpxpic{.5pt}{3}} & Both
    \end{tabular}%
  };

      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \endgroup

  }

\begin{document}%
\noindent
\graph
  {
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
  }

\end{document}


maybe https://ctan.org/topic/gantt could give some inspiration

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264182/drawing-a-really-large-binary-matrix-as-colored-grid

Just for fun, the following uses pxpic to draw the actual grid (disclaimer: I'm the author of pxpic), and then for the axis labels a tikzpicture.
The macro is called \graph and takes an optional and a mandatory argument. The optional argument shall be the width of the pixel matrix including the axis labels.
Please note that the maximum size of a pxpic is limited due to engine limitations in pdfTeX and XeTeX (pxpic's output cost much of TeX's memory).
Changes made by edit: Increase the grid thickness to .2pt, added a legend, altered the width setting to account for the y-axis label (and hence the width should now be (almost) precise).
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pxpic,tikz}

% from pxpic-documentation, minor change in using lightgrey
\newcommand\gridpxpic[3][]
  {{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{#2}%
    \colorbox{lightgray}{\pxpic[gap-hack=-\fboxsep,#1]{#3}}%
  }}

% define a new pxpic style for your charts (monocolored pixels wouldn't need
% that but the diagonally split pixel is non-standard and needs a custom style)
\pxpicnewmode{lukdooxb1}
  {%
    \ifcase#1
      {\color{white}\px}\or
      {\color{orange}\px}\or
      {\color{violet}\px}\or
      \diagpx{orange}{violet}%
    \else
      \GenericError{}{Unknown input symbol #1}{}{}%
    \fi
  }
% definition of the diagonally split pixel
\newcommand\diagpx[2]
  {%
    \begin{pgfpicture}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \color{#1}%
      \pgfusepath{fill}%
      %
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \color{#2}%
      \pgfusepath{fill}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
  }

% auxiliary to count the number of columns and rows (pxpic doesn't need that
% information, it just builds its output as it passes through the list, so we
% can't get this information from it -- we could measure the output of pxpic and
% determine the size that way though)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__lukdooxb_columns_int
\int_new:N \l__lukdooxb_rows_int
\newcount \graphRows
\newcount \graphColumns
\NewDocumentCommand\getCounts{m}
  {
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \lukdooxb_get_counts:n
    \graphRows = \int_use:N \l__lukdooxb_rows_int \exp_stop_f:
    \graphColumns = \int_use:N \l__lukdooxb_columns_int \exp_stop_f:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \lukdooxb_get_counts:n #1
  {
    \__lukdooxb_get_counts_columns:w #1 ~ \q_nil
    \int_set:Nn \l__lukdooxb_rows_int
      { \__lukdooxb_count_rows:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_get_counts_columns:w #1 ~ #2\q_nil
  { \int_set:Nn \l__lukdooxb_columns_int { \tl_count:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_count_rows:n #1
  {
    0
    \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w #1 ~ \q_nil
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w #1 ~ #2
  {
    +1
    \quark_if_nil:nF {#2} \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% the frontend macro (we use .8\linewidth by default as that should fit even
% with the labels)
\newcommand\graph[2][\linewidth]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \getCounts{#2}%
      % set the pixel size such that the size target will be met
      % we'll have to compensate the y-label "Day" which will be rotated (hence
      % we use its depth and height) and offset by 6mm.
      \sbox{0}{Day}%
      \pxpicsetup
        {size=(#1-6mm-\ht0-\dp0)/\graphColumns,mode=lukdooxb1,lines=space}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
           ytik/.style={tik, anchor=south east, xshift=-1pt}
          ,xtik/.style={tik, anchor=north, xshift=-.5ex, yshift=-1pt}
          ,tik/.style={inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize}
        ]
        % here you can change the thickness of the grid lines (the first
        % mandatory argument of \gridpxpic)
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (px) {\gridpxpic{.2pt}{#2}};
        % days ticks
        \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-1\pxpicHT]px.north west) {1};
        \ifnum\graphRows>6
          \ifnum\graphRows>13
            \foreach\x in{7, 14, ..., \graphRows}
              \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-\x\pxpicHT]px.north west) {\x};
          \else
            \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-7\pxpicHT]px.north west) {7};
          \fi
        \fi
        \node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=-6mm]px.west) {Day};
        % worker ticks
        \node[xtik] at ([xshift=1\pxpicWD]px.south west) {1};
        \ifnum\graphColumns>24
          \ifnum\graphColumns>49
            \foreach\x in{25, 50, ..., \graphColumns}
              \node[xtik] at ([xshift=\x\pxpicWD]px.south west) {\x};
          \else
            \node[xtik] at ([xshift=25\pxpicWD]px.south west) {25};
          \fi
        \fi
        \node at ([yshift=-6mm]px.south) (tmp) {Worker};
        % legend
        \node[anchor=north] at ([yshift=-6mm]tmp.south)
          {%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}cl@{}}
              \gridpxpic{.2pt}{0} & day off \\
              \gridpxpic{.2pt}{1} & here \\
              \gridpxpic{.2pt}{2} & there \\
              \gridpxpic{.2pt}{3} & here and there \\
            \end{tabular}%
          };
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}%
\noindent
\graph
  {
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
  }
\end{document}


(thick black border in that screenshot is the result of showframe)
A variant with rounded corners in the legend, please be advised that nesting \tikz inside a tikzpicture is discouraged and might lead to bugs so this here uses four boxes it fills before the tikzpicture and uses those in the legend. For the vertical alignment tweak the baseline=-.1ex in the definition of \legendDot and the \ThreeBox to your liking.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{pxpic,tikz}

% from pxpic-documentation, minor change in using lightgrey
\newcommand\gridpxpic[3][]
  {{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{#2}%
    \colorbox{lightgray}{\pxpic[gap-hack=-\fboxsep,#1]{#3}}%
  }}

% define a new pxpic style for your charts (monocolored pixels wouldn't need
% that but the diagonally split pixel is non-standard and needs a custom style)
\pxpicnewmode{lukdooxb1}
  {%
    \ifcase#1
      {\color{white}\px}\or
      {\color{orange}\px}\or
      {\color{violet}\px}\or
      \diagpx{orange}{violet}%
    \else
      \GenericError{}{Unknown input symbol #1}{}{}%
    \fi
  }
% definition of the diagonally split pixel
\newcommand\diagpx[2]
  {%
    \begin{pgfpicture}
      \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpointorigin}%
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \color{#1}%
      \pgfusepath{fill}%
      %
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pxpicWD}{0pt}}%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pxpicHT}}%
      \pgfpathclose
      \color{#2}%
      \pgfusepath{fill}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
  }

% auxiliary to count the number of columns and rows (pxpic doesn't need that
% information, it just builds its output as it passes through the list, so we
% can't get this information from it -- we could measure the output of pxpic and
% determine the size that way though)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l__lukdooxb_columns_int
\int_new:N \l__lukdooxb_rows_int
\newcount \graphRows
\newcount \graphColumns
\NewDocumentCommand\getCounts{m}
  {
    \tl_trim_spaces_apply:nN {#1} \lukdooxb_get_counts:n
    \graphRows = \int_use:N \l__lukdooxb_rows_int \exp_stop_f:
    \graphColumns = \int_use:N \l__lukdooxb_columns_int \exp_stop_f:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \lukdooxb_get_counts:n #1
  {
    \__lukdooxb_get_counts_columns:w #1 ~ \q_nil
    \int_set:Nn \l__lukdooxb_rows_int
      { \__lukdooxb_count_rows:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_get_counts_columns:w #1 ~ #2\q_nil
  { \int_set:Nn \l__lukdooxb_columns_int { \tl_count:n {#1} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_count_rows:n #1
  {
    0
    \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w #1 ~ \q_nil
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w #1 ~ #2
  {
    +1
    \quark_if_nil:nF {#2} \__lukdooxb_count_rows:w
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% the frontend macro (we use .8\linewidth by default as that should fit even
% with the labels)
\newsavebox\ZeroBox
\newsavebox\OneBox
\newsavebox\TwoBox
\newsavebox\ThreeBox
\newcommand\graph[2][\linewidth]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \getCounts{#2}%
      % set the pixel size such that the size target will be met
      % we'll have to compensate the y-label "Day" which will be rotated (hence
      % we use its depth and height) and offset by 6mm.
      \sbox{0}{Day}%
      \pxpicsetup
        {size=(#1-6mm-\ht0-\dp0)/\graphColumns,mode=lukdooxb1,lines=space}%
      % set the boxes necessary for the legend outside the tikzpicture to avoid
      % nesting
      \newcommand\legendDot[1]
        {%
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.1ex]
            \draw[lightgray, fill=##1, rounded corners=.2\pxpicWD]
              (0,0) rectangle (\pxpicWD,\pxpicHT);
          \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
      \sbox\ZeroBox{\legendDot{white}}%
      \sbox\OneBox{\legendDot{orange}}%
      \sbox\TwoBox{\legendDot{violet}}%
      \sbox\ThreeBox
        {%
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.1ex]
            \begin{scope}
              \clip[rounded corners=.2\pxpicWD]
                (0,0) rectangle (\pxpicWD,\pxpicHT);
              \fill[orange]
                (0,0) -- (\pxpicWD,0) -- (0,\pxpicHT) -- cycle;
              \fill[violet]
                (\pxpicWD,\pxpicHT) -- (0,\pxpicHT) -- (\pxpicWD,0) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
            \draw[lightgray,rounded corners=.2\pxpicWD]
              (0,0)rectangle(\pxpicWD,\pxpicHT);
          \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
           ytik/.style={tik, anchor=south east, xshift=-1pt}
          ,xtik/.style={tik, anchor=north, xshift=-.5ex, yshift=-1pt}
          ,tik/.style={inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize}
        ]
        % here you can change the thickness of the grid lines (the first
        % mandatory argument of \gridpxpic)
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (px) {\gridpxpic{.2pt}{#2}};
        % days ticks
        \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-1\pxpicHT]px.north west) {1};
        \ifnum\graphRows>6
          \ifnum\graphRows>13
            \foreach\x in{7, 14, ..., \graphRows}
              \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-\x\pxpicHT]px.north west) {\x};
          \else
            \node[ytik] at ([yshift=-7\pxpicHT]px.north west) {7};
          \fi
        \fi
        \node[rotate=90] at ([xshift=-6mm]px.west) {Day};
        % worker ticks
        \node[xtik] at ([xshift=1\pxpicWD]px.south west) {1};
        \ifnum\graphColumns>24
          \ifnum\graphColumns>49
            \foreach\x in{25, 50, ..., \graphColumns}
              \node[xtik] at ([xshift=\x\pxpicWD]px.south west) {\x};
          \else
            \node[xtik] at ([xshift=25\pxpicWD]px.south west) {25};
          \fi
        \fi
        \node at ([yshift=-6mm]px.south) (tmp) {Worker};
        % legend
        \node[anchor=north] at ([yshift=-6mm]tmp.south)
          {%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}cl@{}}
              \usebox\ZeroBox & day off \\
              \usebox\OneBox & here \\
              \usebox\TwoBox & there \\
              \usebox\ThreeBox & here and there \\
            \end{tabular}%
          };
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}%
\noindent
\graph
  {
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
    0112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000
    1122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000
    0000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233
    0001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330
    0011223300001122330000112233000011223300001122330000112233000011223300
  }
\end{document}


Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. I still have the comments. 1) How can u add an outer box around the small boxes? 2) How can I add a vertical legend beneath the graphic? 3) Can I adjust/scale the width of the whole plot to \textwidth? You would really help me a lot

@lukdooxb1 what do you mean with "outer box"? Each small box has a light grey frame around it (might not be visible in the rasterisation as the grid lines are only 0.1pt thick). The other points are added by my edit.

Nevermind. Thank you. One issue i am still facing is fontsize. I want to make it smaller than my main text, but \fontsize{}{} doesnt seem to work.

@lukdooxb1 Use font=\small or similar on those \node commands you want to change the font size of. So use something like \node[font=\small].

Thank you, one final question. How can i align only the violet, orange and split box vertically in the legend and add like an outer box with rounded corners to it. Thank you sooo much.

@lukdooxb1 pxpic doesn't support rounded corners, you could however draw the legend using TikZ: \tikz\draw[lightgray,fill=orange,rounded corners=.2\pxpicWD](0,0)rectangle(\pxpicWD,\pxpicHT); vertically centring is possible via the option \tikz[baseline=<offset>], you can play with it until you're satisfied with the results.

Could you possibly add the later option to your code, with vertical alignment. I am really. a total newbie.

@lukdooxb1 added that as a variant.

Thank you. I came up with this code (see EDIT), but somehow the split box is not displayed properly. Why could that be?

@lukdooxb1 because that one is now using rounded corners and your rounding radius (the default value) is too big. Because none of your other pixels in the legend uses rounded corners I'd suggest disabling the rounded corners for that pixel which my edit will do (you can put your changes into the edited version of the second code -- the relevant change is the addition of \pgfsetcornersarced{\pgfpointorigin}).

A method using pgfparser:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[t1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfparser}

\newcommand\workdays[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfparserdef{workdays}{initial}{the character 0}{
      \draw[fill=gray!10] (a) rectangle ++(7pt,7pt);
      \coordinate (a) at ([xshift=7pt]a);
    }
    \pgfparserdef{workdays}{initial}{the character 1}{
      \draw[fill=violet] (a) rectangle ++(7pt,7pt);
      \coordinate (a) at ([xshift=7pt]a);
    }
    \pgfparserdef{workdays}{initial}{the character 2}{
      \draw[fill=orange] (a) rectangle ++(7pt,7pt);
      \coordinate (a) at ([xshift=7pt]a);
    }
    \pgfparserdef{workdays}{initial}{the character 3}{
      \draw[fill=violet] (a) -- ++(0,7pt) -- ++(7pt,0);
      \draw[fill=orange] (a) -- ++(7pt,0) -- ++(0,7pt);
      \coordinate (a) at ([xshift=7pt]a);
    }
    \pgfparserdef{workdays}{initial}{the character .}{\pgfparserswitch{final}}
    \def\myparser##1{\pgfparserparse{workdays}##1.}
    \foreach \line [count=\y] in {#1}{
      \node[font=\tiny,anchor=mid] at (-5pt, -\y*7pt+3.5pt) {\y};
      \coordinate (a) at (0, -\y*7pt);
      \expandafter\myparser\expandafter{\line}
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\workdays{
    00001122330000112231122330000110011330000112233,
    00011223300001122331223300001120112300001122330,
    00112233000011223302233000011221122000011223300,
    01122330000112233002330000112231223000112233000,
    11223300001122330003300001122332233001122330000,
    00001122330000112231122330000110011330000112233,
    00011223300001122331223300001120112300001122330,
    00112233000011223302233000011221122000011223300,
    01122330000112233002330000112231223000112233000,
    11223300001122330003300001122332233001122330000,
    00001122330000112231122330000110011330000112233,
    00011223300001122331223300001120112300001122330,
    00112233000011223302233000011221122000011223300,
    01122330000112233002330000112231223000112233000,
    11223300001122330003300001122332233001122330000,
    00001122330000112231122330000110011330000112233,
    00011223300001122331223300001120112300001122330,
    00112233000011223302233000011221122000011223300,
    01122330000112233002330000112231223000112233000,
    11223300001122330003300001122332233001122330000,
    00001122330000112231122330000110011330000112233,
    00011223300001122331223300001120112300001122330,
    00112233000011223302233000011221122000011223300,
    01122330000112233002330000112231223000112233000,
    11223300001122330003300001122332233001122330000,
    00001122330000112231122330000110011330000112233,
    00011223300001122331223300001120112300001122330,
    00112233000011223302233000011221122000011223300
}
\end{document}



Not that your code is wrong, but note that you can simplify the parser definition by using the shorthand syntax: \pgfparserdef{workdays}{initial}0{<whatever>}

@Skillmon Thanks for your comment. I had missed this detail when reading the documentation (extract: Alternatively you can give the symbol you want without surrounding it in braces.).

Sorry if I wrote that part in an unclear way :P (not to say I created pgfparser, I did not, I merely extended it a bit)

The no separator key from ext.misc of my tikz-ext package takes each token in the list as an element (instead of separating the entries at ,). This token is then fed PGFKeys as /tikz/color matrix/do/<token>. Meaning, all you need to do is create the appropriate keys for the letters/digits you have in your input.
Here, these are
do/1/.style={fill=violet, color matrix/do/rectangle},
do/2/.style={fill=orange, color matrix/do/rectangle},
do/3/.style={color matrix/do/swne triangles={orange}{violet}},

where color matrix/do/rectangle simply creates a rectangle and …/swne triangles creates two triangles with the specified colors.
The \foreach loops counts its entries and uses that value to determine row and column of each entry using the value of /tikz/color matrix/columns.
The rest of the code deals with adding a grid, adding the legend and adding the ticks and axis labels.
The key /tikz/picture width of my ext.scalepicture library is used to scale the whole diagram (including the ticks) to a specific width.
Personally, I wouldn't use this but set a fixed cell width/cell height so that multiple diagrams are consistent in size.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.misc, ext.scalepicture}
\newcommand*\tikzcolormatrixset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/color matrix}}
\tikzcolormatrixset{
  .code=\tikzcolormatrixset{#1},
  at begin/.initial=, at end/.initial=,
  columns/.initial=10, cell width/.initial=+1cm, cell height/.initial=+1cm,
  days ticks/.initial=7, workers ticks/.initial=25,
  every day/.style={anchor=east, xshift=-.5em},
  every worker/.style={anchor=north, yshift=-.5em},
  day legend/.style={node font=\large, rotate=90, anchor=south},
  worker legend/.style={node font=\large, anchor=north},
  every picture/.style={
    every edge/.code=,
    x=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/cell width},
    y=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/cell height}},
  %
  do/rectangle/.style={insert path={(0,0)rectangle(1,1)}},
  do/swne triangles/.style 2 args={insert path={
    (0,0) edge[fill=#1, to path=--(right:1)--(up:1)--cycle] ()
    (1,1) edge[fill=#2, to path=--(up:1)--(right:1)--cycle] ()}},
  do/1/.style={fill=violet, color matrix/do/rectangle},
  do/2/.style={fill=orange, color matrix/do/rectangle},
  do/3/.style={color matrix/do/swne triangles={orange}{violet}},
  %
  grid/.style={at end/.append={
    \draw[gray,step=1](0,1)grid(\tikzcolormatrixcolumn,-\tikzcolormatrixrow+1);}},
  legend/.style={at end/.append={
    \pgfgettransform\pgftransformtemp
    \matrix[column sep=1mm, every cell/.append code=\pgfsettransform\pgftransformtemp,
      matrix anchor=north west] at (tcm-workers.south-|0,0){
      \tikzcolormatrixlegend 0 \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzcolormatrixlegend 1 \pgfmatrixnextcell
      \tikzcolormatrixlegend 2 \pgfmatrixnextcell \tikzcolormatrixlegend 3 \\};}}}
\newcommand*\tikzcolormatrixlegend[1]{%
  \node[anchor=base] (l) {#1}; \tikzset{shift=(l.base east), shift={(.25em,-.3em)}}
  \path[color matrix/do/#1/.try]; \draw[gray,color matrix/do/rectangle];}
\newcommand*\tikzcolormatrixlist[2]{
  \ifnum#2<\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/#1 ticks} #2
  \else\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/#1 ticks}
    \ifnum#2<\pgfinteval{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/#1 ticks}} ,#2
    \else
      ,\pgfinteval{2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/#1 ticks}},...,#2
      \ifnum\pgfintmod{#2}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/#1 ticks}}>0 ,#2\fi\fi\fi}
\newcommand*\tikzcolormatrix[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[color matrix={#1},color matrix/every picture]
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/at begin}
  \gdef\tikzcolormatrixcolumn{0}
  \foreach[
    count=\i from 0, expand list, no separator,
    evaluate={
      \iRow = int(\i/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/columns});
      \iCol = int(mod(\i,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/columns}));}] \v in {#2}{
    \global\let\tikzcolormatrixrow\iRow
    \ifnum\tikzcolormatrixcolumn<\iCol \global\let\tikzcolormatrixcolumn\iCol \fi
    \path[shift={(\iCol,-\iRow)}, color matrix/do/\v/.try];}
  \xdef\tikzcolormatrixrow{\pgfinteval{\tikzcolormatrixrow+1}}
  \xdef\tikzcolormatrixcolumn{\pgfinteval{\tikzcolormatrixcolumn+1}}
  \node[color matrix/every day] (tcm-day-first) at (0,.5) {1};
  \foreach[expand list] \v in {\tikzcolormatrixlist{days}{\tikzcolormatrixrow}}
    \node[color matrix/every day] (tcm-day-last) at (0, -\v+1.5) {\v};
  \node[color matrix/every worker] (tcm-worker-first) at (.5,-\tikzcolormatrixrow+1) {1};
  \foreach[expand list] \v in {\tikzcolormatrixlist{workers}{\tikzcolormatrixcolumn}}
    \node[color matrix/every worker] (tcm-worker-last) at (\v-.5,-\tikzcolormatrixrow+1) {\v};
  \path (tcm-day-last.south west) |- node[near start, color matrix/day legend](tcm-days){Days}(tcm-day-first.north)
        (tcm-worker-last.south) -- node[midway, color matrix/worker legend](tcm-workers){Workers}(tcm-worker-first.south);
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/color matrix/at end}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\tikzcolormatrix[
  columns=36, grid, legend,
  /tikz/picture width=\linewidth,
]{
  101101013101232312101101013101232312
  100101010101232323101101013101232312
  010101110101231223101101013101232312
  111100101001221223101101013101232312
  011000110011231223101101013101232312
  111010101110121223101101013101232312
  101010101110121223101101013101232312
}

\noindent
\tikzcolormatrix[
  columns=11, grid, legend,
  /tikz/picture width=.5\linewidth,
]{
  101101013101232312101101013101232312
  100101010101232323101101013101232312
  010101110101231223101101013101232312
  111100101001221223101101013101232312
  011000110011231223101101013101232312
  111010101110121223101101013101232312
  101010101110121223101101013101232312
}
\end{document}

Output


An implementation using the l3draw package (matrix values stolen from Qrrbrbirlbel's code):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_columns_int
\int_new:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_col_int
\int_new:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int
\dim_new:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_width_dim
\dim_new:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim
\coffin_new:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin

\clist_const:Nn \c_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_codes_clist { 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 }

\keys_define:nn { colormatrix } {
    columns .int_set:N = \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_columns_int ,
    columns .initial:n = { 30 } ,
    width   .dim_set:N = \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_width_dim ,
    width   .initial:n = { \linewidth }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \drawcolormatrix } { o m } {
    \keys_set:nn { colormatrix } {#1}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim {
        \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_width_dim / 
        \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_columns_int
    }
    \draw_begin:
        \str_map_inline:nn {#2} {
            \clist_if_in:NnT \c_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_codes_clist {##1} {
                \int_compare:nNnTF { 
                    \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_col_int 
                } > { 
                    \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_columns_int - 1
                } {
                    \int_set:Nn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_col_int { 1 }
                    \int_incr:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int
                } {
                    \int_incr:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_col_int
                }
                \draw_scope_begin:
                    \draw_transform_shift:n {
                        \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_col_int * 
                        \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim , 
                        \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int * 
                        -\l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim 
                    }
                    \int_case:nn {##1} { 
                        {0} { \color_fill:n { white } }
                        {1} { \color_fill:n { red!50!blue } }
                        {2} { \color_fill:n { red!50!yellow } }
                        {3} { \color_fill:n { red!50!yellow } }
                    }
                    \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0 , 0 } { 
                        \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim ,
                        -\l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim
                    }
                    \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke , fill }
                    \int_compare:nNnT {##1} = { 3 } {
                        \color_fill:n { red!50!blue }
                        \draw_path_moveto:n { \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim , -\l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim }
                        \draw_path_lineto:n { 0 , 0 }
                        \draw_path_lineto:n { \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim , 0 }
                        \draw_path_close:
                        \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke , fill }
                    }
                \draw_scope_end:
            }
        }
        \int_incr:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin { 1 }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin 
            { t } { r } { 0 , 0 }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin { \int_use:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin 
            { b } { r } { 0 , -\l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int * \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin { 1 }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin 
            { t } { l } { \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim , -(\l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int + 1) * \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim }
        \hcoffin_set:Nn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin { \int_use:N \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_columns_int }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnnn \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_temp_coffin 
            { t } { r } { ( \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_columns_int + 1 ) * \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim , -(\l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_row_int + 1) * \l_lukdooxbI_colormatrix_unit_dim }
    \draw_end:
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\noindent
\drawcolormatrix[columns=36, width=10cm]{
  101101013101232312101101013101232312
  100101010101232323101101013101232312
  010101110101231223101101013101232312
  111100101001221223101101013101232312
  011000110011231223101101013101232312
  111010101110121223101101013101232312
  101010101110121223101101013101232312
}
\end{document}


